# Elpy Autocomplete in org-edit-special

Tags: org-babel, elpy

I'm using `org-babel` with python source blocks to put break my code into sections.  The issue I'm having is I don't get any autocomplete suggestions based on the code in other blocks.

Is there any way to have `elpy` recognize the code in the other blocks? I get this could be difficult so my other hope was to have it recognize the code that's already been run in the buffer attached to the source code block?